# Loop over a SimpleJSON array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine, simplejson

I have a Unity project that fetches JSON from a my web server.

```
[
  {
    name: "foo",
    start: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    start: 5,
  },
  {
    name: "baz",
    start: 10,
  },
]
```

I'm parsing the JSON string with [SimpleJSON](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON)

```
  var res = JSON.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text);
```

I have no problem accessing individual array elements.

```
Debug.Log(res[0]["name"].Value);
// logs "foo"

Debug.Log(res[1]["start"].AsInt);
// logs 5
```

But I can't figure out how to loop over each object and access its properties. (my real data has more than 3 objects in the array).

```
   foreach (var item in res) {
        string name = item["name"].Value;
   }
```

Gives the error:

CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'KeyValuePair<string, JSONNode>'

It would be trivial in javascript, why is this so hard in C#? I've been stuck for a whole day, I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Maybe `item.Value["name"].Value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
for (int i = 0; i< res.Count; i++)  //or res.Count()
{ 
   var name res[i]["name"].Value;
....your code
}
```

you can use this too:

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, JSONNode> entry in res)
{
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```

but the first way is more simple.

Comment: That works thanks. I'm rather embarrassed I didn't try that. Can you explain why looping manually is different to using foreach? I thought they were functionally the same.

Comment: Still getting used to stackoverflow, my bad. Accepted now. Could you explain why this works but foreach doesn't?

Comment: @Henry You can use a foreach, it is that the way you were accessing the object was incorrect. The error message you are getting specifies that the type JSONNode is not accessible using []. Whatever object you are accessing the Key of the KeyValuePair is a string, which is accessed properly but your Value is of type JSONNode.